# How to reload data after a post

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to refresh my list after adding new item to it.

This is the component.ts :

```js
addNew(action) {
  if (action == 'add') {
    this.repairerService
      .createNewRepairer(this.repairer)
      .subscribe((x) =>this.getRepairers());
  }
}
getRepairers() {
  this.repairerService.getActiveRepairers().subscribe(data => {
    data.forEach(element => {
      var avatarElement = new ItemRepairerModel();
      avatarElement.id = element.id
      avatarElement.avatar = element.name
      avatarElement.name = element.name
      avatarElement.email = element.email
      avatarElement.phone = element.phone
      this.avatarActiveRepairer.push(avatarElement);
    });
  })
}
```

And this is the component.html :

```html
<ng-template kendoTabContent *ngIf="avatarActiveRepairer.length!=0">
  <kendo-listview [data]="avatarActiveRepairer">
    <ng-template kendoListViewHeaderTemplate>
      <div class="header" class="w100">
        <kendo-textbox class="w100">
          <ng-template kendoTextBoxSuffixTemplate>
            <span class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-textbox>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-listview>
</ng-template>
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Two Solutions:**
1. Add **window.location.reload()** exact below Pushing statement.
 
eg. 
  
addNew(action) {
       if (action == 'add') {
          this.repairerService.createNewRepairer(this.repairer).subscribe((x)=>
           this.getRepairers();
            window.location.reload();
        );
}
}


2.  Add setTimeout() for get request for after every second.

**setTimeout()  sets a timer and executes a callback function after the timer expires.**
```